# Use ssl cert from aws in Hashicorp Vault

Tags: amazon-web-services, hashicorp-vault

How can i use a aws ssl certificate in vault listener.

**In config.hcl file with self-signed cert**

```
listener "tcp" {
  address = "vault.mydomain.com"
  tls_cert_file = "/vault/config/cert.pem"
  tls_key_file = "/vault/config/fullchain.pem"
}
```

Comment: its not clear what the question is @mleaf

Comment: Thank you! i reescribe my question.